# View App in Store link not working even after submission

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I've submitted an app to the store over and hour ago but my itunes connect link to my app is not working.  The app is listed as ready for sale and the symbol is green.  Should I just wait a few more hours or is it possible I missed a step?

Comment: it may take few hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can take a few hours for the new version to be propagated in all the stores.
Just wait.